# Error using \widthof inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newlength{\TextWidth}
    \setlength{\TextWidth}{\widthof{Text}}
    %\node[draw,text width=\widthof{Text}}]{Text}; % this does not work
    \node[draw,text width=\TextWidth]{Text}; % this works
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With the code above I am getting the following error:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@
>
> l.9   \node[draw,text width=\widthof{Text}]{
>                                              Text}

But I am not understanding why, since this code was previously working. I am using TeXLive 2015.

Answer (score 11):

In a `tikzpicture`, the current font is `\nullfont` (see [pp.124-125](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=125), pgfmanual), So `\widthof` can't work.

You may use the `width` function provided by TikZ math engine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,text width=width("Text")]{Text and text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Was this a change for TeXLive 2015?

Comment: Not 100 % sure but it seems that the `\real{⋅}` macro suffers from something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Tikz provides its own version of `\widthof`.  No calc needed.  However the latest version isn't loading it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
% Stuff for calc compatiability.
\let\real=\pgfmath@calc@real
\let\minof=\pgfmath@calc@minof
\let\maxof=\pgfmath@calc@maxof
\let\ratio=\pgfmath@calc@ratio
\let\widthof=\pgfmath@calc@widthof
\let\heightof=\pgfmath@calc@heightof
\let\depthof=\pgfmath@calc@depthof
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,text width=\widthof{Text}]{Text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikzpicture]

Comment: In `pgfmathparser.code.tex`, we found also `\def\pgfmath@calc@widthof#1{width("#1")}`.

Comment: Can you show your `\listfiles`? I can't compile your code with TikZ 3.0.1.

Comment: I have the same code in `pgfmathparser.code.tex`. But still, I cannot compile your code

Comment: If I add those lines in the code within the `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`, your code works. It seems that some package is not being included by default.

Comment: Aha, I updated the MikTex admin version but not the plain version.  Updating the plain version causes me to crash too.

Comment: It would be useful to know from your previous version the packages that are loaded or not.

Comment: This has severe limitations: `\widthof{\bfseries Text}` will die horribly. And it's the same as Paul Gaborit's answer.

Comment: There is always \settowidth, which can be done outside tikzpicture or inside \pgftext (interestingly).

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, here is a robust work-around.  Perhaps someone else can figure out how to make a version of `\widthof` that will work in the Tikz parm parser.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\pgfcalcparm}

\newcommand{\widthof}[1]% #1 = text
{\pgftext{\settowidth{\global\pgfcalcparm}{#1}}%
\the\pgfcalcparm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgftext{\settowidth{\global\pgfcalcparm}{\bfseries Text}}%
    \node[draw,text width=\pgfcalcparm]{\bfseries Text};
    %\node[draw,text width=\widthof{Text}]{Text};% crashes (infinite loop)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error message with TikZ-UML and PGF 3.0.1.

Downloading [version 3.0.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/version%203.0.0/pgf_3.0.0.tds.zip/download) and copying the contents over my TeX tree solved the problem.

Comment: That leaves the question, whether the problem is a regression with hope, that this will be fixed in future versions or if the behavior has changed in 3.0.1 and the problem will remain in future versions.

Comment: That would be interesting to know exactly what is not being loaded and was in the past.