# Array diagram in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, update

I took the answer from the following question: [proportional boxes in Tikz (array diagram)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245251/proportional-boxes-in-tikz-array-diagram)
I had no problem until now, it compiled without any problem, however I just updated Ubuntu and it does not compile anymore.
I am getting the following error

```
\begin{scope} on input line 9 ended by \end{tikzpicture}. \end{tikzpicture} (followed by: )

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ...e[MyStyle, on chain] (vlos\xi) {$\name$};} (followed by: )
```

I tried to update the latex but at the moment the repository is frozen. How can I fix this?

```
\tikzset{
    MyStyle/.style={draw, text width=25pt, text height=10pt, text centered,minimum height=\heightof{$n-2$}+2*2*1mm)},
    myarrow/.style={shape=single arrow, rotate=90, inner sep=5pt, outer sep=0pt, 
                    single arrow head extend=0pt, minimum height=7.5pt, text width=0pt, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!25}

}

\begin{tikzpicture}[-{Stealth[length=2.5pt]}]
\begin{scope} [start chain, node distance=-.5pt]  
  \foreach \name [count=\xi] in {1,2,3,\cdots,k,\cdots,n-k, \cdots,
  n-2,n-1,n}{ \node[MyStyle, on chain] (vlos\xi) {$\name$};}
 \end{scope}
\node[above= 0.1cm of vlos1, xshift=-0.5cm]{$u_{los}$};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror}]
  (vlos7.south west) -- (vlos11.south east) node[black,midway,below=8pt]
  {Removed data};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    -{Stealth[length=2.5pt]}
  ]
\begin{scope} [start chain, node distance=-.5pt]  
  \foreach \name [count=\xi] in {1,2,3,\cdots,k,\cdots,n-k, \cdots,
  n-2,n-1,n}{ \node[MyStyle, on chain] (vlos\xi) {$\name$};
  }
 \end{scope}
\node[above= 0.1cm of vlos1, xshift=-0.5cm]{$u_{bef}$};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror}]
  (vlos1.south west) -- (vlos5.south east) node[black,midway,below=8pt]
  {Removed data};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please provide us with a complete example which produces the error when we try to compile it. How is `\heightof` defined for example?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261940/error-using-widthof-inside-tikzpicture/261986?s=7|0.1360#261986

Answer (score 3):

Replacing `\heightof` with something defined and loading the required TikZ libraries, the code compiles just fine.

[image: modified code]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.arrows,chains,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\newlength\myht
\settoheight{\myht}{$n-2$}
\tikzset{%
  MyStyle/.style={draw, text width=25pt, text height=10pt, text centered,minimum height=\myht+2*2*1mm)},
  myarrow/.style={shape=single arrow, rotate=90, inner sep=5pt, outer sep=0pt, single arrow head extend=0pt, minimum height=7.5pt, text width=0pt, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!25}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[-{Stealth[length=2.5pt]}]
  \begin{scope} [start chain, node distance=-.5pt]
    \foreach \name [count=\xi] in {1,2,3,\cdots,k,\cdots,n-k, \cdots,
      n-2,n-1,n}{ \node[MyStyle, on chain] (vlos\xi) {$\name$};}
  \end{scope}
  \node[above= 0.1cm of vlos1, xshift=-0.5cm]{$u_{los}$};

  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror}]
  (vlos7.south west) -- (vlos11.south east) node[black,midway,below=8pt]
  {Removed data};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  -{Stealth[length=2.5pt]}
  ]
  \begin{scope} [start chain, node distance=-.5pt]
    \foreach \name [count=\xi] in {1,2,3,\cdots,k,\cdots,n-k, \cdots,
      n-2,n-1,n}{ \node[MyStyle, on chain] (vlos\xi) {$\name$};
    }
  \end{scope}
  \node[above= 0.1cm of vlos1, xshift=-0.5cm]{$u_{bef}$};

  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror}]
  (vlos1.south west) -- (vlos5.south east) node[black,midway,below=8pt]
  {Removed data};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (i)  is the arrow on the right end of braces intentional? (ii) in TikZ manual is `text centered` used only in section "27. Using Graph Drawing in TikZ", for other nodes is used `align=center` ... what is more correct?

Comment: (i) I don't know. You'd have to ask the OP ;). (ii) I'm not sure either is more correct but the mention in the discussion of graphs mentions `text centered` as an example of an ordinary option understood by TikZ and not as an option specific to graphs.