# How to make local lengthlike variables in tikz macro's

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, variable

**What am I doing?** I am defining typesetting macro's using tikz.

```
\newcommand[3]{\mycustomtikzmacro}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %commands based on the three inputs named #1, #2 and #3.
        %the number 3 here is arbitrary
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

**What do I want?** In order to prevent the user of the macro's from having to insert many arbitrary numbers, I want to

1. Read off lengths and sizes from the macro inputs given by the user, so I may use them to determine spacing, sizing and positioning within the macro.
2. Store this information in *local* variables, so that the macro may be used more than once.
3. Calculate with this read-off data, including making new variables. Preferably, I do all calculations inside a dedicated "place", as to keep the code as clean as possible.
4. Put the variables I gathered to use in typical tikz commands.

**What kind of answers are most appreciated?** Rather than answers which try to show something that works (which get evry complicated very quickly), I would like explanations of how to use the systems and commands you are showing. My goal is to get insight and to learn to use your answers as a general technique, not to fix whatever specific problem is the reason I'm asking this.

If you want to use examples, please keep them simple and illustrative, and explain the syntax and commands you are using.

---

**Why am I asking?** I have found various answers with various levels of clarity and applicability to my case. My problem is I haven't found a combination of answers that do what I want to do. I also don't have much understanding what the code does in all instances, questions such as "how well does this work together with that, is that a command or a length, is there a difference between a command and a length and a coordinate", so it is not easy to piece things together myself. Hence my question.

**What have I found already?** I can't seem to get point 1 and 2 to work together. One way to have the variables is using lengths and the `\settowidth{}{}` function, which I have made work.

```
\newlength{\x} \settowidth{\x}{$#1$} %stores the width of first input in the new var \x
```

However, in my experience, variables created in this way are global. This means interference with other commands that possibly use the same variable names, and it means that using my macro twice results in errors because a length is defined two times. The only way I've found around this is to initialise the variables at the beginning of every document (see code below). This however leaves traces on the first page, so everything needs to be built around said page being a dummy page...  not exactly ideal.

```
\newcommand{\initailisemycustomtikzmacrovariables}{
    \newlength{\x}%purpose of x
    %\setlength{\x}{whatever value I need} %if this length is a global constant
}
\newcommand[3]{\mycustomtikzmacro}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \settowidth{\x}{$#1$}
        %the rest
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Another option is to make variables within the `tikzmath{}` thingy from `\usetikzlibrary{math}`. It allows me to define local variables and calculate with them (point 3:check), but `\settowidth` does not work here (and \settoheight probably does neither, one might guess).

```
\tikzmath{
    \y = 0.5*\x;
    %slew of other local variables
}
```

[There is a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261940/error-using-widthof-inside-tikzpicture) which suggests various versions of `\widthof{}` commands. I ahven't made this work with any of the two solutions for making variables.

---

EDIT: At the risk of making this even longer, here is a rundown of what does and what does not work. I tried variations on the simple dummy picture below (which should produce ($A$) ) with various ways of using width-functions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{\width = width("$A$")/2;}
    \draw (-\width,0) node {(};
    \draw (0,0) node {$A$};
    \draw (\width,0) node {)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. `\tikzmath{\width = \widthof{$A$}/2;}` does not compile
2. `\tikzmath{\width = width("$A$")/2;}` will compile, but will give lengths approximately 25 times to large.
3. `\tikzmath{\width =0.5;} \setlength{\width}{\widthof{$A$}}` does not compile, as does the version with `width("$A$")`, as does the function `settowidth{}{}`, both with and without semicolons. Placing this command outside the `tikzmath` environment makes it complain about missing numbers and not being able to use the character 0 in some places.
4. Trying all these variants outside the `tikzmath` environment makes it compile past that line, but fail at the next tikzpicture because a paragraph ended before tikz@math@doassignment was complete.
5. `\newlength{}{}\setlength{}{}` does work, but creates global variables. I need to hope thyat nothing else uses `\width` now, and I need to run the `\newlength{}{}` commands in a separate macro that I run exactly once somwhere before I use my macros. I do this either as a manual habit at the beginning of my document, or automatically when i first use one of the macro's (how do I make sure of that). Moreover, it only works with `tikzmath` when I first define a new variable in there (possibly with the same name) and even then the sizes are again too big this time (even though I use `\widthof{$A$}`, `width("$A$")` did not compile).

Point 2 sounds most promising so far. However deviding the value by 20 works for `$A$`, but it doesn't work for `$AAAAAAAAAAAAA$`, so it was not consistent. Are there maybe alternatives there? Mybe there are other width functions.

Comment: `\initailisemycustomtikzmacrovariables` is inserting a space, which will obviously leave a 'trace' in the output. A new line is a space unless commented.

Comment: where and why does it insert a space.

Comment: `\newcommand{\initailisemycustomtikzmacrovariables}{` inserts a space. You need to comment the new line.

Comment: This may very well be my fault, but I do not understand the question. Can you give a concrete example that can not just be resolved by using the pgf parser? E.g. `\settowidth{\x}{$#1$}` can be avoided by using `width("$#1$")` in some expression you parse, i.e. you do not really need a new length as long as you use the result in the Ti*k*Z eco-system,

Comment: BTW, pgf does have internally such lengths like `\pgfutil@tempdima`. You may use them like `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\pgfutil@tempdima}{width("$#1$")}` as long as you wrap your macro in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat this sort of works, in the sense that it compiles wrongly. I tried it with this `\begin{tikzpicture} \tikzmath{\width = width("$A$")/2+3pt;} \draw (0,0) node {$A$}; \draw (-\width, 0) node {(}; \draw (+\width, 0) node {)}; \end{tikzpicture}` (needs the tikzlibrary `math`), but the sizes are way too large. Do tikz and the width function use different units or something?

Comment: No, in the `tikzpicture` `(x,y)` gets interpreted as `x*unit vector 1 + y* unit vector 2`, so in the default setting `(\width,0)` gets interpreted as `(\width*1cm,0*1cm)`. Try `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\tikzmath{\width = width("$A$")/2+3pt;} 
\draw (0,0) node {$A$}; 
\draw (-\width pt, 0) node {(}; 
\draw (+\width pt, 0) node {)}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` instead, this works.

Comment: As I said, this *might* be a very nice question, but I just fail to understand it... (+1 because I am assuming it is my fault. ;-)

Comment: As a high-level matter, it is a question about how to build fine-tuned macros without asking the user to give the macro a bunch of arbitrary-seeming numbers. I want the macro to calculate what adjusting it needs given user input, but that means I need variables to calculate with

Comment: In practice, there are many different constructs to achieve what I wrote above.  commands, lengths, pgfmathsetlengthmacro, tikz coordinates, tikzmath  variables. Maybe some of them are the same, and some of them are not, who knows. I want them to do three different things (be local, calculatable and I want a function for reading of the input dimesions), which some of them might not have, or maybe I need some clever combination, or the right commands.

Comment: However, all things I tried so far have failed. I sense it has to do with some quirks of certain systems, or maybe compatibility issues, or just wrong layout (I believe I had already tried `width()` without the "", to no avail), and I want someone with knowledge about all these systems to tell me what works and what doesn't. they probably will be better at predicting that.

Comment: @cfr I did manage to remove the traces, a few semicolons slipped in and all endlines need to be explicitly commented out (sigh)

Comment: I'm glad that helped with the extra page. I mentioned that because it was the only part of your question I clearly understood. I'm afraid I'm with @Schrödinger'scat and don't really understand the question. The usual way to define extra variables and macros is to put them in a `.sty` file (or, if you will, a `.tex`) and load them in your various documents. Something like `\width` will certainly cause trouble, but `\newlength\korpelwidth` or whatever, probably not. If you really insist, you can use TeX definitions. Then you can overwrite earlier ones, but not just your own.

Comment: Putting it in a `.sty` is what I intend yes. It is true that lengths behave in the way you describe. However, lengths that I define in the `tikzmath{}` environment are actually local. If I define a length in a there, and then use that length in the tikzpicture, it works, but if I try it outside the tikzpicture, LaTeX will complain that a control sequence is not defined, exactly as one would want. Zero interference. Yet the width functions fail. Alternatively I could try running a `\declarecustomlengths` macro the first time one of the macro's of the `.sty` file is run, but I do not know how.

Comment: Well, global stuff is still set in that case. It just isn't the thing you define within the picture. The Ti*k*Z maths library defines a global TeX dimension. That is, it isn't just macros which are being defined when you load it (though why that would be better than lengths or dimensions, I'm not sure). The 'lengths' you define in `tikzmath` are not LaTeX lengths. I don't really understand what you mean about the width functions failing.

Comment: "I don't uderstand what you mean about width functions failing". Well I tried a bunch of stuff, and LaTeX did not give the desired result. I added a minimal working example to the question so you can try for yourself.

Comment: You just need e.g. `(-\width pt,0)` and `(\width pt,0)`.

Comment: thanks that worked. The road to succes was `width("$#1$")` with the `""` and writing `pt` in tikz coordinates. I feel stupid now.